# Comparing if one value fits between other 2

Tags: r

I have 3 values to compare a, b, c. I need to form a loop that returns 1 if b falls between a and c. However they are not linear values. a could be smaller than c and vice versa.

How do I make a if else loop that returns 1 if a<=b<=c Or c<=b<=a and 0 if it falls outside of those bounds.

Comment: How about `b <= max(a, c) & b >= min(a, c) `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `ifelse`, although the recommendation is to avoid using reserved names in `R` as we are using `c` here which is a reserved name:

```
fun_fall <- \(a,b,c) ifelse((a <= b & b <= c) | (c <= b & b <= a), 1, 0)

#example

fun_fall(3,1,3)
0

fun_fall(1,2,3)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse()` for each criteria:

```
ifelse(a<=b & b<=c, 1, 0) + ifelse(a>=b & b>=c, 1, 0)
```

If a, b, and c are vectors of length n, this will return a length-n vector of zeros and ones.

If a=b=c such that both tests are true, you would get a two.  To avoid this, you can wrap the whole expression in `pmin(.,1)` where the dot indicates the above expression, or put both criteria in the `ifelse()` statement like so:

```
ifelse( a<=b & b<=c | a>=b & b>=c, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about introducing `%between%` from data.table for extra readability and ease of coding?

```
    library(data.table)

    a <- 1
    b <- 2
    c <- 3

    b %between% sort(c(a,c)) # TRUE

    a <- 3
    c <- 1

    b %between% sort(c(a,c)) # TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     var check = false;
     if(b>=a)       
     {
        if (b<=c)
        {
           check = true;
        }
     }  
     if (b<=a)
     {
        if(b>=c)
        {
           check = true;
        }
     }
```

not sure about syntax to specified language but that pretty much how you do it